# i have created a excel file using servlet using the jxl jar file in eclipse and now i want to download it but not able to do so?

Tags: java, excel, jsp, servlets

i have used a button in my jsp file download in excel. I have imported the data from oracle database to excel file and when i click the download button ,it generates the excel but i want it to be downloaded from clientside.

```
jsp code..
<body>
<form method="get" action="ViewEmployee">
<input type="submit" name="viewall" value="View All Employees">
</form>
<br>
<form method="get" action="ViewEmployee">
<input type="submit" name="create_xls" value="View in Excel format" onClick="window.location.href='/path/to/excel/EmployeeData.xls'">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: where is the file generated ?

Comment: file is manually generated in the computer as specified by me i.e in my webcontent folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the file as byte array and write it to the setvlet response's output stream as follows.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=file.xls");
        File file = new File("/path/to/excel/EmployeeData.xls");
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        int byteRead;
        while( (byteRead = fileIn.read(outputByte)) != -1){
           out.write(outputByte, 0, byteRead);
        }
        fileIn.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
}
```

Comment: This will write junk at the end of the file, if not before. You're assuming that read() fills the buffer. It isn't specified to do that. As a rule of thumb, it is never correct to call read() without storing the result in a variable.

Comment: Also you don't need to flush before closing.

Comment: how i will invoke this method and after writing the file's content to the output stream ,will the required file be automatically downloaded?

Comment: @Mayank the method is a HttpServlet's doGet http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html so if the servlet is called using get method the file will be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect to the URL of the file that has been generated, and make sure it's visible as a URL.

Comment: actually the file is saved in the folder web content ,it is manually done but how i will make it appear as a url?? help me